# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem with Async Call within the thread

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios

I have a MonoTouch application that use a ThreadPool to manage the number of background threads.  If I have the ThreadPool spawn off a thread and within the thread, it fires an Async web request, will the web request spawn off a 2nd thread? if so, will that thread be taken off of the ThreadPool?

What is the best practice for such a thing?  Should the web request just be a synchronous call, to lower the current thread count?

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback =>
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com/"));
    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (a,b) => Console.WriteLine("Done");
});
```

Comment: Yes, it will be taken from the thread pool, risking exhaustion. What's the point of the double-async in this particular scenario?

Comment: You mean you want to [multitask while you're multitasking?](http://encyclopediadramatica.com/Sup_Dawg)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. My current implementation uses a utility class I built that already fires an async webreqeust, and now am I introducing a ThreadPool to manage touch events, and just realized I am going to be doing a double async.  I want to understand the long term problems I might run into.  Exhaustion seems to be the most obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you´re ending your threadpool callback right afterwards, like you´ve shown there, there shouldn`t be a problem. You´re just replacing one threadpool call timeline with another.